# Bode diagram cutoff frequency in LTspice

Tags: bode-plot

[image]
My question is about the cutoff frequency of Bode diagram.

In the output of this circuit I got this bode diagram normally. When I read the cutoff frequency on -3 dB. But here I don't have -3 dB. Please can someone help me to read this Bode diagram.

Comment: Think about your gain and what -3 dB means in this context.

Comment: @winny what do you mean?

Comment: @marwa Looking at your profile I see you haven't selected any of the answers that were given. It would do you good to take [the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I wanted you to think about what -3 dB means and if your system has any gain (yours has), what that in turn would do.

Comment: @winnyI have questions can I talk to you please in private?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the 3dB **down** frequency which is the gain at the flat portion minus 3dB.
For your plot, the 3dB down point is 16.5 - 3 = 13.5 dB which occurs at about 550 kHz which is the corner frequency.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In LTspice you can find the 3dB down point by adding a second cursor. Click the voltage to plot (in this case V(out)) at the top of the waveform window a second time and you will get a second cursor. Drag Cursor 1 to where it shows the midband level, and then drag Cursor 2 until the cursor results window shows a difference of -3dB. The frequency shown for Cursor 2 will be the cutoff frequency.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help